# JSON Payload with Variable String in Python

Tags: json, payload

I have tried just about all permutations of quotes
Code 1 below is the hardcoded values even this fails with error 400
loaddata =""" {
"Application":"EssbaseHPA" ,
"db": "PerformanceData",
"jobtype":"dataload",
"Parameters": {
"rule":"PerfromanceData.rul",
"file":"DPerformanceData.txt",
"abortOnError": "false"
}
} """

Code 2 is what I am trying to get to work.
Vars are appname,dbname.datafile

loaddata1= "{"Application": appname ,"db":dbname, "parameters":"{ parameters':"file":datafile,"abortOnError":false"}"}"

The above gives unrecognized token appname

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
import json

appname = "hallo"
dbname = "stgres"

a = {
    "Application": appname,
    "db": dbname,
    "jobtype": "dataload",
    "Parameters": {
        "rule": "PerformanceData.rul",
        "file":"DPerformanceData.txt",
        "abortOnError": "false"
    }
}

json_a = json.dumps(a, indent=4)

print(json_a)
```

Comment: Thanks, gave me an idea on another permutation: Below. I had to build up payload with the vars  appname, dbname, datafile below: ldata = "{\"application\":\"" + appname + "\","
        ldata = ldata + "\"db\":\"" + dbname + "\", \"jobtype\":\"dataload\","
        ldata = ldata + "\"parameters\": { \"file\":\"" + datafile + "\","
        ldata = ldata + "\"loaddata\":\"true\", \"abortOnError\":\"false\"} }"  - The key again is the spacing between "parameters": {  Need to have a space on both side of the {..

Comment: Here is the completed request "POST" http://host:9000/essbase/rest/v1/jobs?links=false
{'Authorization': 'Basic yadyadayada=', 'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
Payload with Variable before the post -> 
  {"application":"Vision","db":"Plan1", "jobtype":"dataload","parameters": { "file":"Plan1.txt","loaddata":"true", "abortOnError":"false"} }

Comment: <Response [200]>
JSON= {'job_ID': 41, 'appName': 'Vision', 'dbName': 'Plan1', 'jobType': 'Data Load', 'jobfileName': None, 'userName': 'admin', ''jobInputInfo': {'dataFileName': 'Plan1.txt', 'abortOnError': False, 'useConnection': False}, 'jobOutputInfo': {'recordsProcessed': 0, 'recordsRejected': 0, 'errorMessage': ''}, 'links': [{'rel': 'self', 'href': {'rel': 'Job Status', 'href': 'http://host:9000/essbase/rest/v1/jobs/41', 'method': 'GET'}]}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, gave me an idea on another permutation: Below. I had to build up payload with the vars appname, dbname, datafile below: ldata = "{"application":"" + appname + ""," ldata = ldata + ""db":"" + dbname + "", "jobtype":"dataload"," ldata = ldata + ""parameters": { "file":"" + datafile + ""," ldata = ldata + ""loaddata":"true", "abortOnError":"false"} }" - The key again is the spacing between "parameters": { Need to have a space on both side of the {.

The escaping for " can cause one to go blind.